# RGeo: Plotting a Great Circle on a Mercator Projection

Tags: ruby, geojson, rgeo, mercator, great-circle

I need to trace out multiple shapes on a map, each shape is specified as a type of line between two long/lat coordinates. I have been breaking/interpolating/splitting these lines into a series of points that I've been plotting onto Google Maps (via GeoJSON) which uses a Mercator Projection, and storing it within a postgresql-postgis database.

I have solved this problem for Rhumb Lines, and Clockwise Args, but I'm completely lost on how to trace [Great Circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle). I have been using RGeo to assist with the other line types, and would've expected things to be much easier than I'm finding it.

How do I plot a Great Circle path between two coordinates, with a definable number of steps?

In a fit of late-night coding delirium, I've ported some code samples from C and JavaScript to Ruby. Specifically from [OGR](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/7bfb9c452a59aac958bff0c8386b891edf8154ca/gdal/ogr/ogrgeometryfactory.cpp#L2342) It's a mostly-fine solution, but it's not a reliable solution to say the least, as some of the polygon lines I'm building have begun to overlap, or not leave the expected gaps between converging lines.

I think the answer lines within using a Spherical Factory, but attempting to transform the line string from the spherical factory to a mercator factory only gives me a line with two points.

```
spherical_factory = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326)
point1 = spherical_factory.point(YOUR_LONGITUDE1, YOUR_LATITUDE1)
point2 = spherical_factory.point(YOUR_LONGITUDE2, YOUR_LATITUDE2)
great_circle = spherical_factory.line(point1, point2)
# TODO: Split the great_circle
```

I've even tried ChatGPT for advice, it gives me wonderful code that calls an LineString#interpolate function that does not exist. I would really like a solution that works as simply as that.

Failing any advice, I might try recursively generating an increasing circle from the start coordinate, and building the line from the intersecting points.

Comment: I remember a question I've answered some years ago: [How to generate coordinates in between two known points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22063201/477037) – my answer generates coordinates without an external library. The algorithm is from [www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (ported from JS to Ruby) and not that hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Following some advice, I used PostGIS and the [ST_Segmentize](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html) function.

As I had a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database, with RGeo's support of WKT, I was able to combine the two into a simple algorithm.

```
SRID = 4326 # Used by WGS84 / Google Maps

spherical_factory = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: SRID)
mercator_factory = ... # output factory

# Generate a RGeo Line String for the Great Circle
start_point = spherical_factory.point(point.longitude, point.latitude)
target_point = spherical_factory.point(target.longitude, target.latitude)
great_circle = spherical_factory.line_string([start_point, target_point])

# Segment line using 1km chunks
great_circle_as_wkt = "srid=#{SRID};#{great_circle}"
great_circle_segments = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Segmentize(('#{great_circle_as_wkt}'::geography), 1000)) AS circle;").first['circle']

# Convert the WKT Back into a RGeo Line String
segmented_line = RGeo::WKRep::WKTParser.new(mercator_factory).parse(great_circle_segments)

# Desired Output
segmented_line.points
```

The Spherical Factory probably isn't needed, but would like any additional solution that would use it instead of hitting the database.

This is probably not the most efficient method, but I don't need it to be.